# Comparing against dataset-level aggregates within grouped aggregates

Tags: sql, reporting-services

**Background**

I have a joined table consisting of Incidents, Customers, and Areas that I'm getting from SQL Server 2008 R2.  The query is straightforward and I've picked the relevant fields and filtered out irrelevant data.  I get a ResolveTime field as a datediff(...) I have a matrix tablix that organizes the data in columns grouped by region, then area, and rows grouped by Incident Owner.

The fields show average, count, and (here's where my problem lies) Percent below average.  The same details are computed in a second basic table for the whole dataset.  If you're confused, here's a screenshot of the table.

[image: Table Setup]

**Problem**

The expression I'm using for the percent below average is as follows:

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!ResolveTimeMinutes.Value < avg(fields!ResolveTimeMinutes.Value), 1, 0)) / countrows()
```

When I use this within the matrix it works fine but works based off of the average within the group.  I've tried using the dataset as my scope both for the sum and the average, but both return an error regarding nested aggregates and scopes.  Either I can't nest an aggregate with a scope inside an aggregate, or another aggregate within a scoped aggregate.

I've tried creating a variable that contains the value I'm interested in comparing against, but I'm not allowed to reference that within an aggregate.

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!ResolveTimeMinutes.Value < Variables!avgResolveTime.Value ), 1, 0)) / countrows()
```

This gives me the error that `variable values cannot be used in aggregate functions.`

I've even tried computing the average alone as a separate Dataset and trying to reference that in the comparison, but another error about nested aggregates and what I want to do.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured it out this morning.

I created an internal parameter so that it's not visible in the report, and retrieved the default value from the same Dataset that computed the "GlobalAverage" I was trying to reference directly from the iff function.

**Query:**

```
SELECT avg(datediff(minute, CreatedDateTime, ResolvedDateTime)) as AverageTTR
from incident 
where changeid is null and linkedproblem is null and count_numberoftasks = 0
```

**Expression:**

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!ResolveTimeMinutes.Value < Parameters!GlobalAverage.Value, 1, 0)) / countrows()
```

Works like a charm.  Hope that helps anybody else who might have the same problem!